# run the beta TypeScript compiler for Angular2 in Intellij Idea

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea, typescript1.5

I follow the [angular](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html#start-tsc) (2.0) tutorial and I run the following commands :

```
npm install -g typescript@^1.5.0-beta
```

But in Intellij Idea the TypeScript compiler do not work correctly

[image]

So in the command line options, I try to add

```
-m commonjs -t es5 --emitDecoratorMetadata
```

or

```
--target es5
```

But I have the same problem.
My only solutions for the moment is to run manually:

```
tsc --watch -m commonjs -t es5 --emitDecoratorMetadata app.ts
```

So my question :

**Is there a solution to run the beta TypeScript compiler for Angular2 in Intellij Idea ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add my custom compiler version to IntelliJ in this location:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\typescript\bin
```

along with the command line options `--module commonjs -t es5 --emitDecoratorMetadata`.